# Некорректное добавление записей в БД

Tags: c#, sql

Хочу передать значение некоторых полей в таблицу своей БД. Проблема в том, что добавляется только две записи и не более, даже если объектов в коллекции больше

```
foreach (var item in points)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Stats] (Id, BumpCount, TimeLife)" +
                                    "VALUES (@Id, @BumpCount, @TimeLife)", SqlConnection);

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", item.Id);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BumpCount", item.BumpCount);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("TimeLife", item.TimeLife);
    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
```

Comment: Код вполне рабочий. Как именно вы проверяете что записи добавились?

Comment: В самой VS, только что перенес этот метод в кнопку и все заработало. До этого пытался делать это при закрытии окна в FormClosed и FormClosing

Comment: У вас база лежит в виде файла в проекте и подключена через AttachDbFileName?